# What is the sum of (n-1)+(n-2)+...+(n-k)?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the sum of this series ?

$(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+...+(n-k)$

$(n-1)+(n-2)+...+3+2+1 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

So how can we find the sum from $n-1$ to $n-k$ ?

Answer (score 13):

$$(n-1)+(n-2)\cdots(n-k)=\underbrace{n+n+\cdots +n}_{\text{$k$ copies}}-(1+2+\cdots k)=nk-\frac{k}{2}(k+1)$$

Comment: I edited your post to put the "underbrace" there; I think it makes this sort of thing more readable.  If you don't like it, I won't be at all offended if you revert!

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson Thanks for the edit.

Comment: In most cases that I encounter this, it's comparing all pairwise combinations in a set.  EG A-Z (AB,AC, AD... AZ, BC, BD...) in this case, is k equal to n?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Try writing:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=\sum_{k=1}^{n-k-1}k+\sum_{k=n-k}^{n-1}k.
$$
Your formula allows you to find the first two sums; subtraction should do the rest!

Answer (score 3):

$ n k $ minus the sum from $1$ to $k$ equals

$$ n k - \frac12 k (k+1)$$