# how many was can a set of size n be partitioned into 2 distinct subsets where the ordering does not matter?

Tags: combinatorics

I am studying the equal partition problem as part of my algorithms course.  What I'm wondering is how many ways can a set of size n be partitioned into 2 distinct subsets where the ordering does not matter?

For example, a set S of size 4 might look like this: {1, 2, 3, 4}, then I count seven distinct ways that the set can be partitioned into two subsets.  There are n ways (n = 4) that set S can be partitioned into subsets of size 1, and n-1. For example, you'd have: {1,2,3} {4},  {1,2,4} {3},  {1,3,4} {2}, and {2,3,4} {1}.

Further, there are n-1 ways that set S can be partitioned into sets of size 2 and n-2. For example, you'd have: {1,2} {3,4},  {1,3} {2,4},  and {1,4} {2,3}.  This should continue on as long as 
x <= (n-x) since the ordering inside the subsets does not matter.

So here you'd have a sum of series: n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + (n-x), but again this only continues as long as x <= (n-x).  If someone more mathematically inclined than myself could assist me in deriving a general sum of series for this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $2^{n-1}$ ways to partition a set of $n$ elements into two subsets.  This includes the case where one of the subsets is empty: you left that out of your example with $n=4$.  If you mean to count partitions into two **nonempty** subsets, that is $2^{n-1}-1$.

The reason is that there are $2^{n}$ subsets of your set of $n$ elements, but since a subset and its complement generate the same partition you have to divide by $2$.

Comment: thank you for your help. can you explain to me why the solution wouldn't look like the solution posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556807/what-is-the-sum-of-n-1n-2-n-k    is it because the first term is not n?

Comment: @TrixietheCat: You're counting the number of ways for each size wrong. There are many more than 99 ways to divide a set of size 100 into subsets of size 2 and 98, for example.

Comment: @Robert Israel, thank you for taking the time to help a struggling student!